# How should I design a program to read from multiple streams of data?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm writing a program which uses two different streams of data to perform certain calculations.  I currently have my code set up like this:

```
//pseudo c++

class Calculator
{
    //Stream is a class which contains a queue which has new messages added to it
    Stream a, b;

    bool BothQueuesHaveItems() { return !a.IsEmpty() && !b.IsEmpty(); }
    void PerformCalc() { /*Do domething with the first items in a and b*/ }

};


unsigned ThreadFunction(void *stop_event)
{
    Calculator calculator;

    while(WaitForSingleObject(stop_event) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        if(calculator.BothQueuesHaveItems())
        {
            calculator.PerformCalc();
        }
        Sleep(5);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Event stop_event = CreateEvent(...);
    CreateThread(ThreadFunction, &stop_event, ...);

    //wait for user enter command to stop processing
    SetEvent(stop_event);
}
```

This doesn't seem like a very good design (particularly the continuous looping in the ThreadFunction whether there are new items in the queues or not), but I'm not exactly sure how to improve it.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IsEmpty`, instead just read a character from the stream.  The read will block until a character is ready (at least, in *nix, not sure about Windows).

So something like

```
pair <char,char> nextItems() { return make_pair(a.readChar(), b.readChar()); }
```

should work fine.

The only trouble is implementing your `stop_event`.  `nextItems` will wait forever, so you'll need to put the reading code in a separate thread and have stop_event exit the process directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use Win32 overlapped (asynchronous) reads, or create a thread for each stream in order to do synchronous, blocking reads.